# Rotate and save a photo in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I want to upload photos in server. But before that I want to rotate that image.
My code is like below,

```
    $photo = $request->file($field);
    $temp = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
    $rotated = imagerotate($temp, 270, 0);
    $extension = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $flieNametoStore = time()."___".explode('.',$photo->getClientOriginalName())[0].'.'.$extension;
    Storage::disk('public')->put($flieNametoStore,  $rotated);
```

It is not working. It shows error like `supplied resource is not a valid stream resource`.
I also tried `Storage::disk('public')->put($flieNametoStore,  File::get($rotated));` but still it doesn't work.

So, I have two questions. 
What can I do to achieve my objective? (rotate and save in server.)
Also, I have used imagecreatefromjpeg function. However, I want to execute same code for other file type.(All types supported by laravel validation of image.)

I searched in SO and found some similar questions. However, those solutions are not giving me my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use imagejpeg function for save photo

imagerotate return a gd resource type not resource...

```
$photo           = request()->file($field);
$temp            = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
$rotated         = imagerotate($temp, 270, 0);
$extension       = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
$flieNametoStore = time() . "___" . explode('.', $photo->getClientOriginalName())[0] . '.' . $extension;
imagejpeg($rotated,  $flieNametoStore);
```

or

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($rotated);
$rotated = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
Storage::disk('public')->put($flieNametoStore, $rotated);
```

Comment: I tried this one too. However, it is not saving in the correct folder. Is there any way to combine "Storage::disk('public')->put()" with imagejpeg?

Comment: use ob_get_content way:
 ob_start();
 imagejpeg($rotated);
 $rotated = ob_get_contents();
 ob_clean();
 Storage::disk('public')->put($flieNametoStore, $rotated);

Comment: Thank you. It worked.Can you tell me how I can execute similar code with png and other file types?

Comment: you can use this code     $mimeType = $photo->getMimeType();
    if ($mimeType === 'image/jpeg') {
        $temp = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
    } elseif ($mimeType === 'image/png') {
        $temp = imagecreatefrompng($photo);
    } elseif ($mimeType === 'image/gif') {
        $temp = imagecreatefromgif($photo);
    }

Comment: but remember save all by jpg extention